# LARAVEL | Group By Query Edit

Tags: php, laravel, api

I'm have this query:

```
        $result_status_count = TWTask::whereRelation('assignee', 't_w_assignees.user_id', $user->id)
        ->groupBy('status_id', 't_w_statuses.name') // count all task group by status for all users.
        ->join('t_w_statuses', 't_w_statuses.id', 't_w_tasks.status_id')
        ->selectRaw('t_w_statuses.name, count(*)')
        ->get();
```

and the result is:

[image]

but I'm  need the Result Like:

```
[
 {
   "Processing": 1
 },
 {
   "Rejected": 4
 },
 { 
   "Completed": 6
 }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `pluck`.

For example, `....->get()->pluck('count(*)','name');`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `case` query if you have static list of status e.g

```
select 
sum(case when status = 'Processing' then 1 else 0 end) Processing,
sum(case when status = 'Rejected' then 1 else 0 end) Rejected,
sum(case when status = 'Completed' then 1 else 0 end) Completed
from table_name
```